# Python kill scripts

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I need to kill all python scripts except one. Unfortunattely, all scripts have similar name "pythonw.exe". Difference in PID only.

First time, i don't need to leave one script alive, thats why i just kill all python scripts in system by `taskkill /F /T /IM "python*"` command.

But now, i have one script, that automates all other scripts. The script is my simple "testing system". It rewrite object script, start, stop and restart.
But my problem is multithreading in objective script (10 - 20 threads).

I don't know, how to kill all python threads, except automates one.

P.S.
I tried to get tasklist and PID of automates script, and killed all scripts, except that one, but it doesn't work (i don't know why)

P.P.S
OS: Windows XP
Python 2.7.8

Comment: Add some meta layer so that you can exit the processes in a controlled way; otherwise, it’s a real mess…

Comment: Pretty much never kill a thread; have it exit normally by setting a global flag or queuing a request for it to exit. Windows has `TerminateThread`, but Python doesn't expose it, thankfully. It leads to resource leaks and possibly an inconsistent process state, an even inconsistent state across processes if the thread was in the middle of updating shared global data.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, sometimes my object script don't work normally and i must kill all his threads.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is place testing code in exe file. Now i can kill all python scripts, as previously. Maybe someone will offer another solution?